# [[PromiseState]]: "rejected" in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react in javascript and I try to encrypt array elements using a loop, then I want to push each result  in an element of the new array, I use this code:

```
   var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");
    
   var privateKey= Buffer.from([238, 239, 199, 101, 188, 134, 13, 13,195, 172, 125, 168, 225, 189, 72, 148, 225, 200, 127, 218, 204, 11, 150, 146, 180, 243, 195, 109, 200, 119, 50, 20],'hex');
   


  let array = [2,3,5];
  let array2=[];


    for (let b of array) {
          
          const a= eccrypto.sign(privateKey,b);
          array2.push(a);

        }
        console.log(array2);
```

the problem is it rejected in the second and fourth elements.
The result is like this:
[image]

and the error message:
[image]

I tried to use async/await as a lot of the previous problems solved by using it, but I get the same problem.

I'll appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following way

```
import eccrypto  from 'eccrypto'
import crypto from 'crypto'

export default function App() {
  let array = [2,3,5];
  
let array2=[];
 
  var privateKey = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
  for (let b of array) {
    var msg = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(b).digest();
    eccrypto.sign(privateKey, msg).then(function(a) {
      array2.push(a);
      
    });
    
  }
  console.log(array2);
```

Comment: actually, it works, thank you so much. but I wonder why when I am using this code outside a loop it doesn't give me an error: `const a= eccrypto.sign(privateKey,b);` which b=2

Comment: also when I use this code it generates the same hash even the value is different.

Comment: try crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pwd).digest('hex');

Comment: if you have a look, I write about this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860490/crypto-createhashsha256-return-same-hash-when-input-different-values