# crypto.createHash("sha256") return same hash when input different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use this code but I get the same hash with each element in the array even they are different, can anyone know why this happens?

```
  let array = [2,3,5];
  let array2 = [];

   var privateKey = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
    for (let element of array) {

      var msg = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(element).digest('hex');
      console.log(msg);

      var d= eccrypto.sign(privateKey, msg);
      
        console.log(d);
     
      array2.push(d);
                     
    }
  
    console.log(array2);
```

this the output of array2:

[image]
for notice when I use "md5" like this:

```
var msg = crypto.createHash("md5").update(b).digest('hex');
```

it works well!